# How to set Google Cloud Storage ACL with GD image functions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gd, google-cloud-storage

I am using "imagepng" to create some thumbnails in my application.

How can I specifically set the ACL for Google Cloud Storage so the file is publically available?

I know I can set the entire bucket to be as such, but I'm interested in being able to do this for the image functions, as well as other file upload methods (the docs only talk about file_put_contents, which I'm not using)

Answer (score 2):

Use the ACL "public-read". There's [an example of serving such a thing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access#serving_files_directly_from_google_cloud_storage) in the documentation. Example:

```
$options = [ "gs" => [ "Content-Type" => $fileType, "acl"=>"public-read" ]];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents("gs://hooliapp.appspot.com/".$fileName, $file, 0, $ctx);
$object_public_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl('gs://hooliapp.appspot.com/'.$fileName, true);
```

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to tell imagepng how to specify a Content-Type when saving the file, so you'll need to modify the Content-Type after you save the image as a separate action.